# Google sheets formula to remove currency sign

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Which formula can I use to remove the currency sign?

Anything smarter than: `REPLACE(value,0,1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is way too vague.

Having said that, let's cover different conditions

- Cell as **TEXT**  `=C1*1`
- Cell as **NUMBER** `=N(C2)`
- **Raw Value**     `=("$-123.55")*1`

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity. Which one of the proposed formulas solve your issues? If not, what was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

`=SUBSTITUTE(value, "$", "")`